# Get the list of all lambda functions created in an AWS cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to create a custom cloudwatch dashboard using cloudformation, which displays various metrics of all lambdas that would get created from the same cloudformation template.

Is there a way we could get the list of all lambdas that were created as part of the template that can be passed as reference to the cloudwatch dashboard resource?

I am unable to find any documentation of AWS that can help me with this problem.

Comment: You can programmatically [describe resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-resources.html) for a given stack and filter the results by resource type of `AWS::Lambda::Function`.